# Android Espresso: How to import LongListMatchers in v2.0?

Tags: android-espresso

How do I import the Espresso's [LongListMatchers](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testapp_test/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/testapp/LongListMatchers.java) class?  I'm trying to use the `withItemContent` method, but haven't been able figure out how to import that functionality.  In my `build.gradle` file I have:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
}
```

I'm able to use matchers like `onView`, `withId`, and `click`, so I'm pretty sure my core configuration is working properly.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
onData(withItemContent("Short Headline 1"))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.headlineListView))
    .perform(click());
```

Answer (score 4):

LongListMatchers is a sample that demonstrates how to write your own matchers for an Activity that uses an adapter (in this case a ListView). It is specific to that activity and lives in espresso-sample (in espresso 2.0). If you see something in there that you believe should be moved into the core library, feel free to open a feature request on android-test-kit.

Comment: Thanks Valera!  I'm just new enough to Java that I wasn't sure about that.  I started reading up on the Hamcrest matchers last night. Will post the solution once I get it working.